# Show submit button as an image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place a form button inside a table cell which is displayed as an image. I could simply set the input type to image, however I don't want the mouse coordinates to be passed to GET.

This is what I've tried:

html:

```
<form action='php/like.php' method='get'>
    <input type='submit' id='like' title='like' name='id' value='<?php echo $value[id]; ?>' />
</form>
```

css:

```
#like {
    background: url('images/star.png') no-repeat;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

This is my result (tested on firefox and chrome):
[image]

How can I get the image to be displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
font-size:0;
```

into the class it will get rid of the text that overlays the submit button.

Comment: Thank you, however I'm asking how I can get the image to be displayed. At the moment it's not showing up.

Comment: All the code is correct, i'd suggest looking at the path you are giving are providing, the fact that it is blank suggests that it cannot find the image at the location that you have provided. Here is a fiddle to show you the difference, the first one works the second (like yours) doesn't have a valid file path http://jsfiddle.net/K7Es2/2/

Comment: Oh I'm stupid. The CSS file wasn't in the root folder. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
it works , the only cause if it is not not working is 404.  
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    #like {
        background: url('smiley.gif') no-repeat;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action='php/like.php' method='get'>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $value[id]; ?>" name="id"/>
        <input type='submit' title='like' id='like'/>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```